# Javascript - removing space/s that are immediately followed by a linebreak

Tags: javascript

My problem is simple, but I cannot figure it out. I have a simple form (textarea) where user enters some text and this text is saved in a database. The issue is - I want to remove unnecessary spaces before the text is saved. So I created a simple Javascript function:

```
str.replace(/\n\s*\n\s*\n/g, '\n');
```

But it does not remove the spaces when user posts a text like:

```
hello world     \nanother sample           \n test
```

(so when user adds a space/spaces after the last word AND then posts another word in a new line, these spaces are left (and saved in database as):

```
hello word    <br>another sample         <br> test
```

etc.

What I need is that these spaces followed by a new line are removed by Javascript so that the result is:

```
hello word<br>another sample<br>test
```

Comment: regex is your friend ;)

Comment: believe me, it's not (I wish it was though;)

Comment: Your regexes matches only sequences of whitespace that contain at least 3 linebreaks. Use `\s*\n`.

Comment: Try this way `str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to simplify your regular expression:

```js
const input = 'hello world     \nanother sample           \n test';
const output = input
  // Remove all whitespace before and after a linebreak
  .replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, '\n');
console.log(output);
```

Or if you want to see it as it will be saved in your database:

```js
const input = 'hello world     \nanother sample           \n test';
const output = input
  // Remove all whitespace before and after a linebreak
  .replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, '<br>');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @Tom Glad I could help!